# Duplicated token update device request

Tags: ios, device, mdm, ota

I've noticed that device during MDM enrollment (after installing configuration profile) sends duplicate Token Update request.

First goes Authenticate what is ok:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
    <key>MessageType</key>  
    <string>Authenticate</string>  
    <key>Topic</key>  
    <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.c708ft49-9595-4bd0-a6e2-9d9f234c5458</string>  
    <key>UDID</key>  
    <string>e446679f06cb220e056bf57gf4518735beb2a775</string>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

And here is Token Update:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
    <key>MessageType</key>  
    <string>TokenUpdate</string>  
    <key>PushMagic</key>  
    <string>D4562B52-AC38-77A6-BE95-2A199410BAC9</string>  
    <key>Token</key>  
    <data>  
    PCDC0ogSLzcHKFyVSGNJLgty/SlMbTTR/Xz67196GTM=  
    </data>  
    <key>Topic</key>  
    <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.c708ft49-9595-4bd0-a6e2-9d9f234c5458</string>  
    <key>UDID</key>  
    <string>e446679f06cb220e056bf57gf4518735beb2a775</string>  
    <key>UnlockToken</key>  
    <data>  
    REFUQQAABORWRVJTAAAABAAAAARUWVBFAAAABAAAAAJVVUlEAAAAEBC0YxFZ7UZTgAcA  
    U9Qmi49ITUNLAAAAKIEuErMLEEc3eVZI0+wrq0p7dEV24/ut+8HLaJIvaNS4G/6FuP4q  
    Tu5XUkFQAAAABAAAAAFTQUxUAAAAFOrZutuk5SPjlqRjD0G1EzP5t34JSVRFUgAAAAQA  
    AMNQVVVJRAAAABDaPKoxXPdBP6FqQdWWFO5/Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAABV1JBUAAAAAQAAAAD  
    S1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAAChFiqFGCSnaeY6F0VLx3L1yPSiZYFC1ItQWno1uoHKt  
    yw7nQDjlleCtVVVJRAAAABBQmNg1/jJLwbCoMEiNQ4P3Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAACV1JBUAAA  
    AAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAABV1BLWQAAACiYaUBi44zRzCIuY/3BlkPyz9uzV76b5sdw  
    Vd1GcIGWSXTIcl9Lbo7YUEJLWQAAACBQ2646mc3kBp3Xmyvo/9WDW727Z8As7p7YlPrW  
    QDffFFVVSUQAAAAQ3dMHH4/MQaqhpakX2IvDoUNMQVMAAAAEAAAAA1dSQVAAAAAEAAAA  
    A0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoSdaf/l+x/BgHfUty8TljEhi+/Yoo/T0EirnDdkAS  
    sxBVxYe+s7eew1VVSUQAAAAQGWf/o/XRT8mmudz0wea7hENMQVMAAAAEAAAABVdSQVAA  
    AAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoHxsUm34O4O+g4euZFjAJKiB4Wg4f+lvt  
    f9Ap5AOxY+49GnN3nrCORFVVSUQAAAAQvliCNGUBS6iqzN223WsmCENMQVMAAAAEAAAA  
    BldSQVAAAAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoMY/G6CqrXXoQ0S05AYGkzWGX  
    MdBGZ3syFZ67cQvbz/r/sEozHvuedlVVSUQAAAAQrSVjtmatQjOEzB8MI+uqjENMQVMA  
    AAAEAAAAB1dSQVAAAAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoTT0alk6RGwwDqhry  
    bqxfqrWGl5DvbKPChIvJWghe2wje1qSpq42tiFVVSUQAAAAQiDIRPjluRTqeyogSmjjC  
    RkNMQVMAAAAEAAAACFdSQVAAAAAEAAAAAUtUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAgLg4NUgQ/  
    wUGT7ln/HUdPJwrsyjSyHyT4HPt+h5CTLzZVVUlEAAAAEMhN1PsN2E17kjIvZmsGic5D  
    TEFTAAAABAAAAAlXUkFQAAAABAAAAANLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZAAAAKKScYu84RcZ/  
    8ZB3IQmI/GT3ZMKdZPUliOuM3gI6oJvCDCnpBzvBnU9VVUlEAAAAEMkSLY7arkfltYzC  
    4UWGyDdDTEFTAAAABAAAAApXUkFQAAAABAAAAANLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZAAAAKBMb  
    AusUm9eK/ebTOZIcLxst6m57nS9nbvHVCuuRpLFG1lKchqT695ZVVUlEAAAAEJldIM5B  
    7UgVj+z6dsR3xdFDTEFTAAAABAAAAAtXUkFQAAAABAAAAAFLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZ  
    AAAAIJlCZHxNJgosRkzOQypYRJtH3lq9D5GfjA/NhEKISU/DU0lHTgAAABT8i5TLNvSa  
    IpuOepnvMaKXre9EQg==  
    </data>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

After returning 200 from the server I receive again Token Update with the same values:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
    <key>MessageType</key>  
    <string>TokenUpdate</string>  
    <key>PushMagic</key>  
    <string>D4562B52-AC38-77A6-BE95-2A199410BAC9</string>  
    <key>Token</key>  
    <data>  
    PCDC0ogSLzcHKFyVSGNJLgty/SlMbTTR/Xz67196GTM=  
    </data>  
    <key>Topic</key>  
    <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.c708ft49-9595-4bd0-a6e2-9d9f234c5458</string>  
    <key>UDID</key>  
    <string>e446679f06cb220e056bf57gf4518735beb2a775</string>  
    <key>UnlockToken</key>  
    <data>  
    REFUQQAABORWRVJTAAAABAAAAARUWVBFAAAABAAAAAJVVUlEAAAAEBC0YxFZ7UZTgAcA  
    U9Qmi49ITUNLAAAAKIEuErMLEEc3eVZI0+wrq0p7dEV24/ut+8HLaJIvaNS4G/6FuP4q  
    Tu5XUkFQAAAABAAAAAFTQUxUAAAAFOrZutuk5SPjlqRjD0G1EzP5t34JSVRFUgAAAAQA  
    AMNQVVVJRAAAABDaPKoxXPdBP6FqQdWWFO5/Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAABV1JBUAAAAAQAAAAD  
    S1RZUAAAAAQAAAAAV1BLWQAAAChFiqFGCSnaeY6F0VLx3L1yPSiZYFC1ItQWno1uoHKt  
    yw7nQDjlleCtVVVJRAAAABBQmNg1/jJLwbCoMEiNQ4P3Q0xBUwAAAAQAAAACV1JBUAAA  
    AAQAAAADS1RZUAAAAAQAAAABV1BLWQAAACiYaUBi44zRzCIuY/3BlkPyz9uzV76b5sdw  
    Vd1GcIGWSXTIcl9Lbo7YUEJLWQAAACBQ2646mc3kBp3Xmyvo/9WDW727Z8As7p7YlPrW  
    QDffFFVVSUQAAAAQ3dMHH4/MQaqhpakX2IvDoUNMQVMAAAAEAAAAA1dSQVAAAAAEAAAA  
    A0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoSdaf/l+x/BgHfUty8TljEhi+/Yoo/T0EirnDdkAS  
    sxBVxYe+s7eew1VVSUQAAAAQGWf/o/XRT8mmudz0wea7hENMQVMAAAAEAAAABVdSQVAA  
    AAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoHxsUm34O4O+g4euZFjAJKiB4Wg4f+lvt  
    f9Ap5AOxY+49GnN3nrCORFVVSUQAAAAQvliCNGUBS6iqzN223WsmCENMQVMAAAAEAAAA  
    BldSQVAAAAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoMY/G6CqrXXoQ0S05AYGkzWGX  
    MdBGZ3syFZ67cQvbz/r/sEozHvuedlVVSUQAAAAQrSVjtmatQjOEzB8MI+uqjENMQVMA  
    AAAEAAAAB1dSQVAAAAAEAAAAA0tUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAoTT0alk6RGwwDqhry  
    bqxfqrWGl5DvbKPChIvJWghe2wje1qSpq42tiFVVSUQAAAAQiDIRPjluRTqeyogSmjjC  
    RkNMQVMAAAAEAAAACFdSQVAAAAAEAAAAAUtUWVAAAAAEAAAAAFdQS1kAAAAgLg4NUgQ/  
    wUGT7ln/HUdPJwrsyjSyHyT4HPt+h5CTLzZVVUlEAAAAEMhN1PsN2E17kjIvZmsGic5D  
    TEFTAAAABAAAAAlXUkFQAAAABAAAAANLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZAAAAKKScYu84RcZ/  
    8ZB3IQmI/GT3ZMKdZPUliOuM3gI6oJvCDCnpBzvBnU9VVUlEAAAAEMkSLY7arkfltYzC  
    4UWGyDdDTEFTAAAABAAAAApXUkFQAAAABAAAAANLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZAAAAKBMb  
    AusUm9eK/ebTOZIcLxst6m57nS9nbvHVCuuRpLFG1lKchqT695ZVVUlEAAAAEJldIM5B  
    7UgVj+z6dsR3xdFDTEFTAAAABAAAAAtXUkFQAAAABAAAAAFLVFlQAAAABAAAAABXUEtZ  
    AAAAIJlCZHxNJgosRkzOQypYRJtH3lq9D5GfjA/NhEKISU/DU0lHTgAAABT8i5TLNvSa  
    IpuOepnvMaKXre9EQg==  
    </data>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

Have anyone had the same problem? Why is it duplicated. I've observed this behaviour on IOS 6,7 and 8. So is it Apple's bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: One more clarification UnlockToken in the second payload is different, however I still don't understand why it is sent twice...

Comment: Which MDM are you using?

Comment: I'm creating my own MDM server. All according to iOS documentation (3 phases). It works all fine, however I don't understand why in check-in Token Update is 2 times. Any ideas?